# CakePhp: how to set a select using $this->Form->input with values from 1 to 100?

Tags: forms, cakephp, select

I am using Cakephp and I would like to learn how to set a select with values from 1 to 100?

Please notice I prefer to use `$this->Form->input` if possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**TLDR:**

```
echo $this->Form->input('whatever', array(
    'type'=>'select',
    'options'=>array_combine(range(1,100), range(1,100))
));
```

**Explanation:**

PHP's `range` creates an array of numbers (or letters), which is what you want for your options.  But if you use `range` by itself, it creates:

```
array(1,2,3,4...
```

This would give you a dropdown of numbers, but the values will start with zero regardless of the displayed number - in this case, you'd end up with `array(0=>1, 1=>2 ...`

When you really want this:

```
array(1=>1, 2=>2, 3=>3 ...
```

By using `array_combine` just makes it so the first option has the same value as the displayed number.

(obviously you can write this in 1 line - I just broke it up for ease of reading)